# Inherited TreeView control in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: user-controls

I need to inherit the asp.net Treeview for fixing a rendering issue. I am currently trying to accomplish that in an Sharepoint project that also contains various other things like webparts, aspx, images, etc.

I tried to do it like this the first time:

```
namespace MyNamespace.Controls
{
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:TreeViewAdv runat=server>")]
    public class TreeViewAdv : TreeView
    {
        public override void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            base.RenderBeginTag(writer);
            if (base.DesignMode)
            {
                writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Tr);
                writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I now try to use that control in an aspx inside that assembly, I am not able to reference the control with a statement like this:

"<%@ Register TagPrefix="custom" Namespace="MyNamespace.Controls" %>"

The question is: Is this supposed to work? Do I really have to create a second assembly for that only hosting server controls (hope not)?

Every hint is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Holger

Answer (score 1):

The Register tag most likely needs to have an assembly attribute.

Unless you add the assembly hint to the `<pages>` element in web.config

You may also need a `<SafeControl>` element

Is your library getting installed into the GAC?

Comment: Yes, it is added to GAC. There is a safecontrol element added with type *, that all types of the namespace are safe. Didn't add it to pages in web.config (as this assembly has only a app.config that is somehow not added to the web.config, may be this is an issue?). 
I also tried it with the assembly attribute, without version but no luck. It didn't work either.

Comment: If you dont add the full assembly (including version) name to either pages or Register, then asp.net doesnt know how to find your control.

Comment: It doesn't help. I'll go write some testers for that. Meanwhile I could solve my issue without inheriting the treeview, so there is no pressure behind it.
Thanks anyway for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive you need to your class assemblies via the package designer, like below
[image]

After that you can reference your assemblies in your solution like below

[image]

Hope this helps.